# How to resolve missing SELECT keyword error when trying to insert select

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

It doesn't matter how I write this statement, I always get the ORA-00928 missing select keyword error.

I'm trying to insert values from a query into a table. The result of the query has the same amount of columns as the table where it needs to be inserted to. I have tried making it as an CTE. Even a select-query from an existing table returns the same error.

Code is like:

```
WITH FIRST_CTE(FrstCol1,FrstCol2)
AS
(
  SELECT 't', '1' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 's', '2' from dual
)
,

SECOND_CTE(SndCol1,SndCol2)
AS
(
  SELECT 't', '3' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'z', '4' from dual
)

INSERT INTO TABLE_1
SELECT *
from 
(SELECT * FROM FIRST_CTE) A
JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM SECOND_CTE) B
ON A.FrstCol1 = B.SndCol1
;
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The code in your question looks fine.

Comment: How many columns do you have in table_a?

Comment: @Rob Blagg, There are four columns in table_a I have also tried to just use insert into table_a without specificying the columns, same error occurs.

Comment: are you typing this into a tool or is it from a script file? if script file, check the line terminator (e.g. you have CRLF line terminators while running the script on Linux).

Comment: I am typting this within SQL Developer on a SQL Worksheet. I have declared a lot of CTE's, following a select statement. I want to insert the outcome of the select statement into TABLE_A. The error occurs on the line where 'insert into' is written, on column 3. I can't figure out why.

Comment: Are you sure the names of table_a and table_b are not reserved words?

Comment: Is that the actual SQL statement, or the real one is convoluted?

Comment: The real one is too complex to show here, so this is where it comes down to.

Comment: In SQL Developer make sure your INSERT starts in line 1, because otherwise the error line will point at the wrong line.

Comment: @Adder names of tables already cannot be the reserved words. e.g you even cannot create those ones in that case.

Comment: `create table "SELECT" (ID integer);` works just fine @BarbarosÖzhan

Comment: what about using "SELECT" within the above insert statement @Adder ?

Comment: It works as long as you use the double quotes.

Comment: OK, your first suggestion doesn't make sense then @Adder

Comment: @The Impaler, I've edited the code to be more similar to the real code used in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem occurs if you put `INSERT` part to the beginning, since `SELECT` statement starts by `WITH` clause ( for this case )

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_1
WITH FIRST_CTE(FrstCol1,FrstCol2)
AS
(
  SELECT 't', '1' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 's', '2' from dual
)
,

SECOND_CTE(SndCol1,SndCol2)
AS
(
  SELECT 't', '3' from dual UNION ALL
  SELECT 'z', '4' from dual
)
SELECT *
from 
(SELECT * FROM FIRST_CTE) A
JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM SECOND_CTE) B
ON A.FrstCol1 = B.SndCol1;
```

provided that `TABLE_1` is such a table that is created as

```
create table TABLE_1(FrstCol1 varchar2(100),FrstCol2 varchar2(100),
                      SndCol1 varchar2(100), SndCol2 varchar2(100))
```